# Create an encapsuled forked github environment

Tags: github

I want to create an environment where I have only a portion of a large project. this is for the developers, they can then commit their changes and I can do pull requests to the master on another repository. I thought about achieving this by forking the project -> deleting some stuff and creating a branch but, when I do a pull request it adds the deleted items as well. Removing some files is also for security purposes / sensible data, so it is necessary. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Best Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider adopting a separate git repository and using git submodules to embed it in large projects.

Some Advices:

1. Separate development and production environments and use fake data for verification.
2. Do not add your confidential data to the git repository at any time.
3. If data versioning is required, use a more professional option and not to be confused with other assets.